# Ubuntu Install issues

Tags: system-installation, raspberrypi

I am installing ubuntu on a raspberry pi 4 and I am unable to get it installed. I checked to see if the other repositories are available and they are all available. (multi universe etc.) I am still getting the ”unable to locate package ubuntu.”

Comment: How are you trying to install Ubuntu? It is not a package.

Comment: I type "sudo apt install ubuntu" and I get unable to locate package ubuntu"

Comment: Who told you there is a package called "ubuntu"?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Comment: I am installing ubuntu on a raspberry pi 4 and I am unable to get it installed. I checked to see if the other repositories are available and they are all available. (multi universe etc.) I am still getting the” unable to locate package ubuntu.”

Comment: There is no `ubuntu` package. That's why you are getting this message.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4 by running

```
sudo apt install ubuntu
```

You need to download an Ubuntu iso file from [HERE](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi), write it to a USB stick or a SD card, then boot from it and follow the installation process.

For a detailed tutorial see:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi